# How to call a function when a node is being viewed?

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

Whenever I view a node page, I want to call a function but I'm not sure how to do that.

I was thinking I should use `hook_menu()` and declare the path as node/%, and attach a callback function to that path. Is that the right way, or is there a correct/better way?

Comment: is this very simple to answer?

Comment: Yes the answer's very simple, but I'm not sure why that makes this a bad question. The downvote seems unnecessary IMO. I edited to clarify and make it obvious that you've though about this yourself, hopefully that'll be enough to appease the nay-sayers :)

Comment: I must admit Clive's edit significantly improved readability of this question :) +1 from me. Questions simple to answer when you know the answer are not always bad, it's sometimes hard to search them on the net or drupal.og docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)

> Act on a node that is being assembled before rendering.

e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'the_type' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // Call your function here.
    my_function($node);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module can also react to URL access. You can specify an *action* supposed to happen on *event* if *condition* is true.

- Event: Content is viewed
- Condition: Probably  'Textual Comparison' on [site:current-page:path]
- Action: If none of already provided meets your needs, you can [provide your own function as Rules Action](http://drupal.org/node/878928).